# Incorrect output sankey diagram when using shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, sankey-diagram

When I create a sankey diagram in a regular R session the output looks ok. The tooltip shows an arrow between the connections:

```
require(rCharts)
require(rjson)

links <- matrix(unlist(
  rjson::fromJSON(
    file = "http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/energy.json"
  )$links
),ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
nodes <- unlist(
  rjson::fromJSON(
    file = "http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/energy.json"
  )$nodes
)

links <- data.frame(links)
colnames(links) <- c("source", "target", "value")
links$source <- sapply(links$source, FUN = function(x) {return(as.character(nodes[x+1]))}) #x+1 since js starts at 0
links$target <- sapply(links$target, FUN = function(x) {return(nodes[x+1])}) #x+1 since js starts at 0
sankeyPlot <- rCharts$new()
sankeyPlot$setLib('http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey')
sankeyPlot$set(
  data = links,
  nodeWidth = 15,
  nodePadding = 10,
  layout = 32,
  width = 960,
  height = 500,
  units = "TWh",
  title = "Sankey Diagram"
)
sankeyPlot
```

[image]

When I create it in `shiny`, the arrow in the tooltip is replaced by unusual characters. Also below the plot an unusual character is printed. I needed to download the d3_sankey library to make the shiny app version work, so if you want to reproduce it you have to change the path in the `setLib` statement. How can this be fixed?

```
require(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('Test'),
    sidebarPanel(  'Test'  ),
    mainPanel(
      chartOutput("Plot", 'C:/R-3.0.1/library/rCharts/libraries/sankey')  
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){

    output$Plot <-  renderChart2({
      sankeyPlot2 <- rCharts$new()
      sankeyPlot2$setLib('C:/R-3.0.1/library/rCharts/libraries/sankey')
      sankeyPlot2$set(
    data = links,
    nodeWidth = 15,
    nodePadding = 10,
    layout = 32,
    width = 960,
    height = 500,
    units = "TWh",
    title = "Sankey Diagram"
      )
      return(sankeyPlot2)
     })
  }
))
```

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Belgium.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Belgium.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Belgium.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Belgium.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.8.0.99 rjson_0.2.13   rCharts_0.4.2 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-6    caTools_1.16    digest_0.6.4    grid_3.0.2     
 [5] httpuv_1.2.1    lattice_0.20-23 plyr_1.8        Rcpp_0.10.6    
 [9] RCurl_1.95-4.1  RJSONIO_1.0-3   tools_3.0.2     whisker_0.3-2  
[13] xtable_1.7-1    yaml_2.1.10
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you are facing. The Shiny app runs fine and the tooltips show up the arrow. I suspect that this might be due to an encoding issue. Can you print your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: I added it. OS= windows 8.

Comment: Ah Windows 8 + Non UTF-8 encoding. This is going to be fun to resolve :)  I am convinced it is an encoding issue. Let me think what would be the best way to resolve this.

Comment: Ok, thanks! In the meantime, is there a work-around?

Comment: Having the same issue here but there seems no answer yet.

Comment: I just encountered the same issue. The Sankey plots work fine in RStudio until I try to put them into an RShiny App, which is the logical next step for these graphs. It definitely looks like a character encoding issue. I'm running Windows 7 OS, R version 3.2.4, RStudio 0.99.902, RShiny 0.13.2. Hoping for a work around...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to character encoding in multiple files. This is how I resolved the issues on my Windows 7 machine.

1. Mouseover tooltip issue

An arrow character is used to construct the "link" between source and target.  It occurs in these files:

```
example_build_network_sankey.html
layouts\chart.html
layouts\chart_static_title.html
layouts\chart.html
```

Replace the arrow with the ASCii characters ->
so the code looks like:

```
.text(function (d) { return d.source.name + " -> " + d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });
```

2. Characters below the chart

ï»¿ is found in:

```
\libraries\highlighters\prettify\css\sunburst.css
\layouts\chart.html
\libraries\widgets\d3_sankey\layouts\chart.html
```

I used the Search and Replace in Files facility in UltraEdit to replace this special character with a blank space. This one is tricky because I could not see the character in the UE editor. If I highlighted the blank space it appears as a backtick. The character is also found in jquery-1.8.2.min.js.

Comment: Hint: `ï»¿` are the 3 bytes of the [UTF-8 byte order mark](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) (hexadecimal EF BB BF) which text editors don't display in Unicode text mode according to Unicode standard. In __Save As__ dialog of UltraEdit it can be set with an option to save a UTF-8 encoded Unicode file without or with BOM. In UltraEdit there are also 2 configuration settings which define saving UTF-8 encoded files without or with BOM by default.